# Bootstrap dropdown required in Chrome is not working with empty value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm currently using a dropdown menu which requires to choose a country from the list. The thing is the code is working as intended in FF (2nd option which is an empty value does NOT mean that required step is done) while chrome just ignores the problem and thinks the empty value is OK.

Here is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Country" required>
    <option selected value="">Choose Your Country</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="country1">Country1</option>
    <option value="country2">Country2</option>
    etc
```

Any ideas what is the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't your empty `value=""` supposed to be on the default label (Choose Your Country)?

`<select class="form-control" name="Country" required>
    <option value="">Choose Your Country</option>
    <option disabled value=""></option>
    <option value="country1">Country1</option>
    <option value="country2">Country2</option>
</select>`

Comment: I want to have an empty option/space before the list of countries starts.

Comment: Try using `disabled` in the blank option. (Edited answer.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!